# Java : how reference is selected for method or constructor?

Tags: java

In below code I have some doubt in following line :

```
btn.addActionListener(this);
th= new Thread(this);
```

code :

```
public class Foo  extends Applet implements  Runnable,ActionListener
{
    Button btn;
    Thread th;
    public void init()
    {
        btn=new Button("Click on me");
        add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(this);  // pass reference as this
        th=null;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        int i=0;
        while(i++<10)
        {
            try{
                th.sleep(500);
                showStatus(new Integer(i).toString());
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(th==null)
        {
            th= new Thread(this);  // pass reference as this
            th.start();
        }       
    }
}
```

in Thread class constructor **`Thread(Runnable target)`** Allocates a new Thread object.
We can pass Runnable Target but I have passed ***this*** as parameter. I have implemented Runnable interface though it is possible
But again I have passed ***this*** as parameter In this case we can pass **ActionListener** target.
If we pass ***this*** as parameter in both the cases how It can get resolved.
I think  ***this*** reference is targeting  to reference  of
1. Foo
2. Runnable
3. ActionListener
so how suitable reference is selected for method or constructor?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a IS-A relationship :

- `Foo` IS-A `Applet`
- `Foo` IS-A `Runnable`
- `Foo` IS-A `ActionListener`

When new object of type `Foo` is created , `Foo` will be "selected reference" type. You have to cast to others if you want to have different type (from the selected list).

As long as `Foo` IS-A `Applet`, `Runnable` and `ActionListener`, the contract of the methods are fullfiled : `btn.addActionListener(this);` takes `Foo` which IS-A `ActionListener`, `th= new Thread(this);` takes `Foo` which IS-A `Runnable`.

Answer (score 2):

The method signature of the method you are calling determines what "'this' is targeting", whatever that's supposed to mean. addActionListener() takes an ActionListener parameter; new Thread() takes a Runnable; etc.

Comment: I mean that in  addActionListener() method we can pass ActionListener as parameter but I have pass this and it is not only target to 
ActionListener
but also 1. Runnable &  2. Foo class 
So how it distinguish..

Comment: @MaheshMeniya EJP's answer is completely correct. The object `this` is an `Applet` which also contains all methods from `Runnable` and `ActionListener` classes. This is a relatively basic Java concept; you can read up on some of it [in the Java docs on polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), and more broadly in the [interface and inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) documentation.

Comment: @MaheshMeniya It doesn't have to 'distinguish' anything. If 'this' is an instance of a class that implements Runnable, ActionListener, etc., the code will compile. If not, not.